# Calculate table score based on column combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to build a query to calculate the table score based on a column combination in the table.

So, I have table 'A' that contains database metadata.

| DE_Type | Column_Name | Table_Name | Data_System_Instance | Database_Name | Data_Element_Counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | SalesName | tbl_sales | DB_PROD | Daily_Sales | 40 |
| Govt_ID | SSN | tbl_sales | DB_PROD | Daily_Sales | 40 |
| Name | CustName | tbl_customer | DB_PROD | Daily_Customer | 5200 |
| Name | PIC | tbl_supplier | DB_PROD | Daily_Supplier | 21 |
| Email Address | Email | tbl_supplier | DB_PROD | Daily_Supplier | 21 |
| Phone Number | Handphone | tbl_supplier | DB_PROD | Daily_Supplier | 21 |

and table 'B' as a parameter table

| ID | DE_1 | DE_2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Govt_ID | 3 |
| 2 | Name | Passport | 3 |
| 3 | Name | Email Address | 2 |
| 4 | Name | Phone Number | 2 |
| 5 | Govt_ID | Email Address | 1.5 |

I am imagining will have an output like this:

| Table_Name | Data_Element_Counts | DE_Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tbl_sales | 40 | 3 |
| tbl_supplier | 21 | 4 |
| tbl_customer | 5200 | 1 |

Table_Name is obtained from Table 'A' Table_Name;
Data_Element_Counts is obtained from Table 'A' Data_Element_Count;
DE_Score is the hardest part, it needs to gather all DE_type from single table, then lookup to table 'B', to find whether the collected columns have a combination like in table 'B' (DE_1 & DE-2)

So, how can I develop a query to have an output like this?

Comment: How do you determine `table A`'s `DE_Type` is `DE_1` or `DE_2` in `table B`? And how do you get `DE_Score = 1` for `tbl_customer`?

Comment: I need to find whether all DE_Type in single colum have combination in table B. So, table B containing the possible combination of Data element (DE). for tbl_customer, because there is no combination found, I gave it score '1'

Comment: How about the first question on `DE_1` and `DE_2`?

Comment: For example, in the tbl_sales, there are two DEs contain in that table. DE_Type 'Name' and 'Govt_ID'. Then, lookup to table 'B' to find the combination, which is ID '1', that combination of 'Name' and 'Govt_ID', then we assign the score to the output table.

Comment: How do you decide for `(DE_1, DE_2)`, it is `(Name - Govt_ID)` or `(Govt ID - Name)` ?

Comment: table 'B' is like reference table. So the idea is, list all DE_Type in each table (tableA.Table_Name), and check to the reference table, whether there is a combination of DE_Type (DE_1 and DE_2 is the combination). Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

As you did not explain how the `DE_1` - `DE_2` comes about, I assumed, you need to use all possible combination of `DE_Type` to match with the parameter table.

The first CTE finds the combination of `DE_Type` after that join to the parameter table to get the `Score`.

For the case of `tbl_customers` it will not have any match with the parameter table at all. And it handled separately and `UNION` with the matching result.

```
with 
combi as
(
  select t1.Table_Name, 
         t1.Data_Element_Counts, 
         DE_1 = t1.DE_Type, 
         DE_2 = t2.DE_Type
  from   meta t1
         inner join meta t2 on  t1.Table_Name = t2.Table_Name
                           and  t1.DE_Type   <> t2.DE_Type
),
final as
(  
  select c.Table_Name, 
         c.Data_Element_Counts, 
         DE_Score = sum(p.Score)
  from   combi c
         inner join para p on c.DE_1 = p.DE_1
                          and c.DE_2 = p.DE_2
  group by c.Table_Name, c.Data_Element_Counts
)
select Table_Name, Data_Element_Counts, DE_Score
from   final 
union all
select Table_Name, Data_Element_Counts, DE_Score = 1
from   meta m
where  not exists
       (
           select *
           from   final x
           where  x.Table_Name = m.Table_Name
       )
```

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, thanks for your suggestion. Really appreciate it.